# PHP: Trying to get contents of a HTML textbox

Tags: php, html, xampp

I'm trying to get the contents of a text box, and if its a certain text, I want it to display a message. I keep getting errors though.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Name Tester</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Name Tester!</h1><br>
            <p>Type your first and last name in the name box and see results!</p>
            <p>EX: Name: John Smith</p>
            <FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="post">
                Name: <input type="text" name="firstlastname" value="firstlastname"></input>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></input>
            </form>
            <?PHP
            $firstlastname = $_POST['firstlastname'];
            if($firstlastname == "John Smith"){
                echo "John Smith is the most used name ever. Just letting you know.";
            }
            elseif($firstlastname == "First Last"){
                echo "That isnt much of a name, whats your REAL name?";
            }
            ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The error I get on the `localhost/index.php` is:

```
Notice: Undefined index: firstlastname in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 15
```

The HTML still displays and the php still works, but I am getting this rather annoying error. I'd like to remove from my website.

Comment: Do you get the error when opening the page for the first time or after filling something into the field and submitting it?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['firstlastname'])){ $firstlastname = $_POST['firstlastname']; }

Answer (score 0):

You get this error if you are trying to access the variable that has not been set. In this case the "firstlastname" in your $_POST is not set or undefined (because that might be empty when you submit the form).

You can either turn off the PHP notice (error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE );) -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

OR you can also check to see if "firstlastname" has been set using isset($_POST['firstlastname']) before trying to access it in line15 of index.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your code in the PHP block with an if statement checking if the button has been pressed yet. You're not going to have anything in your post array until you post something to there (by submitting the form).